# HTML styling table issue

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code? Basically I want the table to be styled so it has the border, the BG color and aligned to the top.

Thank you.

```
<td style="border: solid 2px #111111;" bgcolor="#d9e2f4;" vertical-align:top;">
```

Comment: You want to style table or td?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have styles outside of the inline `style=""` declaration.

```
<td style="border:solid 2px #111111;background:#d9e2f4;vertical-align:top;"></td>
```

Ideally, the styles should be separated from the HTML. Place them in their own stylesheet.

```
table td {
  border:solid 2px #111111;
  background:#d9e2f4;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This is exactly what I needed as it requires to be done with HTML as I'm using an online platform with no access to stylesheets.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your whole code but it should be:

```
<table class="yourClass">
   <tr>
      <td>....</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and the css code should be:

```
.yourClass{
    border: solid 2px #111111; 
    background-color: #d9e2f4;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```